# Shared library update

Tags: dll, linker, dylib, shared-libraries

I have my application splited into 4 main parts:

1. **main application** (acting like a glue for other parts - load plugins, has linked **core** and **ui** libraries)
2. **core** (shared library with classes etc., it will be even something like sdk, basically contains all except things related to **Ui**)
3. **ui** (shared library, that contains ui resources, types etc.)
4. **other plugins** (shared libraries, loaded by main application, which will use Plugin manager from **core**

The main reason for this is that i want to have possibility to replace all parts of application just by downloading plugins for my application (through plugin manager window in that application).

Let's say i want to redesign look of my app. In that case i should just release new version of **ui** shared library/plugin.

I am not sure if it will work, if that ui shared library is linked to my app by linker when application is compiled (**core** and **ui** are linked by linker, other shared libraries/plugins are loaded by plugin manager when app is starting).

**Question**:There will be probably saved some metadata about those libraries in final executable, for instance size?? So i probably can't just replace **ui** shared library, without need to compile and link my app again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can replace a shared library with an other version of the shared library in distribution (without recompilation of the executable, etc.) in case the original library and the replaced library  **do have**  same [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)